# LXDE: gracefully logout instead of killing all running applications

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

On Windows, when you logout, each application receives the equivalent of Alt+F4, so if you have an unsaved document in Word, it will show a message asking you to save it.

In LXDE, instead, each program just closes, even though I have unsaved documents. It seems each program receives a SIGTERM instead of an Alt+F4 equivalent.

Is there a way to change that behavior?

Comment: Doesn't seem limited to LXDE. I'm seeing the same behavior in Xfce.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no. But keep in mind this is a minimalist DE for a reason. Apparently, its Makers declared such features too bloaty. They might be right though.

UNIX already allows for the graceful closing of child processes through SIGTERM. Unresponsive children can be killed immediately with SIGKILL. Sensible DEs follow this design, sending SIGTERM, then following up with SIGKILL only when necessary. Some applications, like libreoffice, do not follow this design and shut down immediately when they receive SIGTERM, even if there are unsaved documents. The Makers rightfully consider this a problem with libreoffice and not with their session manager.

Closing all clients of an X11 session gracefully can be more complicated than just sending alt-f4 to all windows. For instance, if you have multiple firefox windows open and you send alt-f4 to all at the same time, the windows will close individually, in a random order. When firefox starts up again, only the last window to close will open again. Thus SIGTERM is actually the *right* signal to send to the firefox process if you want all windows to start up again in their previous state.

For reasons I don't understand, most interactive shells don't respond to SIGTERM, so xfce4-terminal and many others will just send SIGKILL to their clients. The result is that terminals generally respond very badly to alt-f4. The only way to ensure there is no data loss is if each terminal is closed individually, with the user judging whether there is a task in the terminal that must be completed before closing it.

That said, if you find alt-f4 to be appropriate for gracefully closing all applications you use on a day-to-day basis, it should be fairly easy for you to write a simple script that sends an alt-f4 to all running windows. The relevant X11 event is `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`. There's some information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85205/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-a-close-event-on-various-windows-using-the-terminal) on how you might write such a script. It is even possible to filter out the troublesome clients, like firefox and terminals. Now imagine the Herculean task of maintaining such a script for all X11 applications people are likely to use and you can see why most DEs opt for the UNIX-style SIGTERM, SIGKILL approach.

Comment: Great answer, but keep in mind, SIGTERM can't be "cancelled". For example, you have unsaved documents in Word, and you click logout in Windows, the OS sends the request to all apps. Word displays the "Do you want to save?", Yes/No/Cancel. If you click Yes or No, Word closes, but if you click Cancel, Word doesn't close and Windows cancels the Logout. With SIGTERM, the process that does the call HAS NO WAY to find out how the process responded, and also, SIGTERM is not blocking, so the process can't display a message box and wait for you and respond then.

Comment: SIGTERM can be cancelled, in that it can be ignored. A good DE should not log out if a client is ignoring a SIGTERM and only send SIGKILL after the user asks it to force logout. Whether this is actually what happens is another story. So, there may be more even a simple DE like LXDE can do here, without complicating the design.